# How to show only recently created pages in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm just getting to grips with Google Analytics for a site I'm doing some content management for, and want to know how to look at the traffic for pages created recently/in specific timeframes.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to log the page creation date as a custom dimension. Then you'd need to select your timeframe, and filter by your custom dimension (via regex, since you cannot apply the date filter to a custom dimension).

If the page does not have any hits in the selected timeframe it will not show up at all. And in any case you will see only metrics from the hits in the selected timeframe, even if the page has been created before that.

So this is sort of possible, but rather more complicated than one would assume.